# Как правильно произносить слово "фольклор"?

Tags: фонетика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произносится слово "фольклор": с твердой или мягкой Л? В языках романской группы (по крайней мере, в латинском, итальянском и испанском) Л всегда мягкая, а как быть с этим словом?
Спасибо

Comment: Повтор вроде http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/23110/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре Резниченко (2010 год) даются два варианта: фолькл(ё)р и фолькл)о)р, мягкий вариант на первом месте.
Слово заимствовано в начале 20 века из англ.языка, где folk - народ,  lore - мудрость.

Comment: Да, но у англичан "l" - твёрдое. Почему у нас "лё"?

Comment: Я не считаю, что мы должны один к одному копировать чужую фонетику, приоритетным в этом случае является удобство произношения слова. Думаю, что произносить твердый Л сложнее, чем мягкий,  - возможно, здесь сказывается влияние первого мягкого звука Л.

Answer (score 0):

В орфоэпическом словаре - фольклор, а мягкое произношение указано как допустимое.

Comment: В каком именно словаре? Кстати, у меня есть академический словарь под ред. Аванесова (1987 год), и там, действительно, мягкое произношение только допускается. Но прошло 20 лет, и ситуация меняется.

Comment: У меня Аванесов 1985-й год. Толстый, черный.
А кто такой Резниченко? Напишите, пожалуйста, что за словарь.

Голова крУгом: Аванесов-Резничеко-Розенталь.
А где филологи Ивановы-Петровы-Сидоровы?! 
Шутка.

Comment: Резниченко - это она, Ирина Леонидовна. У меня их два: Словарь ударений русского языка (2004 год, очень интересный, с текстовыми примерами, историей изменения ударения, описанием различных акцентных групп) и Современный (орфоэпический) словарь русского языка. Ударения. Произношение. (2010 год). Автор уважаемый и часто цитируемый в разных передачах, посвященных правильному русскому языку.

Comment: Спасибо!
Обязательно куплю эти словари.
А то у меня один авторитет - Розенталь. И я была твердо уверена, что в МГУ продолжают его дело: дополняют и изменяют пособия и словари.
Спасибо за открытия.